# What is the expansion of space of one megaparsec in one year?

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, space-expansion, universe, estimation

suppose we know Hubble's constant. In a hypothetical scenario an astronomer finds and confirms Hubble's law for a galaxy 1 mega parsec away.
Next year, how much distance will the hypothetical astronomer measure?

Comment: If for example you take SPR-3G's recent estimate of 68.3 km/s/Mpc, just multiply that many km/s by a year, to get about a 14.4 AU expansion. Good luck measuring that small of an increase.